# Is it possible for iPhone's MAC or other network specifications to change through update to IOS 14?

Tags: ios, wifi, mac-address

NOTE!!!
I already know that MAC address is static and is about the hardware's address. But i don't know what's happening,
Here is what got me wondering.

On the router in our house I set MAC filtering so that only our devices can connect.

Recently after i updated my iPhone 7 to IOS 14, i had my phone joined to the same wifi, but once i felt like i have a slow connection, i changed network to mobile data.

After a couple of days i found out that i don't have any message or email notification popping up when I'm on WiFi and there was the time i knew i have no access although I'm connected to the WiFi network.
So i searched for solutions. People suggested restarting my phone, resetting network setting and these sort of things(non of em worked).

Just a few minutes before, i reset the router and as a result, all the MAC restrictions are gone and its working properly.
I also think there might be other things that could change through this reset, but i cant work it out.
Moreover i changed the router's configuration (network name and passphrase) a couple of times before; another waste.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, iOS 14 introduces a new type of MAC address randomization named "Private WiFi Addresses". This means that iOS selects a new, random MAC address for each WiFi network you connect to. Note that only the first time you connect a new address will be chosen - it stays the same for that network the following times you connect.

You can disable this behavior from the Settings app on the phone. Choose WiFi and then press the (i) button for the network in question. Ensure that "Private Address" is not enabled.

Comment: Relevant Apple post is here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211227